# How to get npm module on client side using NodeJS

Tags: meteor, npm

I tried npm module on client side.First i declare server side

```js
Youtube = Meteor.npmRequire "youtube-video-api"
```

But I want YouTube value on client side.How to i get this one.

Comment: How did you declare it server side?

Comment: Youtube = Meteor.npmRequire "youtube-video-api" this one server side and  package.json "youtube-video-api": "0.3.4" i added.I dont know how to get youtube value on client side.

Comment: The syntax is the same on both server and client side.

Comment: I tried client side var youtube_video = require('youtube-video-api'); but i get console error Uncaught Error: Failed to require "youtube-video-api" from "root".